# Java multithreading and timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm trying to multithread my java application with `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. I do this by submitting the tasks to the future list and then try to retrieve the results from the future list. However, for some reason, it still only utilizes one core on the computer when I run htop.

In addition, the processes sometimes hang, which i suspect to be because of the libraries i'm using, so what would be a good way to implement essentially a time limit, after which the thread restarts with a new object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot kill a thread safely you cna only interrupted is so it cna shut itself down.  If you need to kill a thread running alibrary you need to run in is a seperate process.

To use more than one CPU you need to have more than one CPU intensive task. If you are running one task at a time, you will use at most one core.

Comment: Would I simply use a try catch statement for the interrupt to start a new thread then?

And the task consumes 99-100% of the cpu, but what do you mean \one task at a time?

Comment: If you don't catch the exception, the thread will stop. I mean there is only one task running at any given moment.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean that there is one task running at any given time. Does that prevent use of the other cores on my machine?

Comment: Ah nevermind. I was running the wrong class file.. woops. haha. Sorry about that.

Comment: Each task will use at most one core. To use more than one core, you need to have multiple independant tasks running at the same time.